# Firebase Cloud Firestore Social network database design

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a simple question. I am building a Instagram clone app and I want to show each user to their friends. Also they can see the friends list. I am using cloud firestore approach. However I'm a little bit confused about how to store user's friends data? . Should I create a new collection as friendsList

[image]

[image]

or should I hold the data in users collection as a friends array ?

[image]

In the first approach I will create the user data again when some user adds a new friend. Am a new for both firestore and NoSql I would be thankful If anyone can explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to "answer" as such, but explain the philosophy of NoSQL a bit.  The best approach is to design your *queries* first (i.e. what do you want to get from the database), *then* design your database schema to make getting the results of those queries efficient and affordable.  There are many ways to organize data; you want to take advantage of NoSQL "schema-less" to make your schema match *your* needs, not the other way around.

Other things to keep in mind: DRY is *less* critical to NoSQL.  Static data (i.e. never or rarely changes) can be stored in multiple places (i.e. a friend's *name* might be in their profile *and* in a friends-list) if that saves reads & writes (which are the biggest factor in costs).

So how to organize *your* database?  I don't know; what do you want *your* database to *do*?

Comment: @LeadDramer Actually I was happy for my first approach in my application. But there is a one problem..Ex: When I update my displayName I should update every single document that my displayName referenced. I mean I need the update multiple collections for single property and I think it is not a good thing for every application.

Comment: How often does that happen?  if it's less than the number of times you need to look UP a name, then it's more economical to have it in all the documents that need it.

Comment: @LeadDramer if a user changes the display name or profile photo i should update both posts collection and friendslist collection that referenced by this user. If a user has 100 friends and 5 posts I should update 100 data in friendslist collection and 500 post in timeline collection I can use firebase functions for that but still I don't know If it is a good way to update every document ??

Comment: Can't answer "good" - it's *your* application;you'll have to decide what's important, what you want to allow your users to do, etc.  Does the "old" image or name matter to the user?  How often will *any* user change name or image or whatever?  Design your *APP* first, *then* design your database to fit.

Answer (score 1):

I should read to this tutorial.This [tutorial](https://www.codedodle.com/social-network-friends-database/) about is MySql but not important for me if you understand this tutorial you can apply firebase.

*I leave a tip below.*

[image]

Comment: I already read this document but when the NoSql structures different I cant decide which way is the best also I don't have any status or action in my application. I didn't make complicated like this yet.

Comment: My opinion this is very simple structure.Of course you can do what do you want.